# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Crashing When Merging .cshtml Files

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2015

When I try to merge cshtml files in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, I kept getting this generic error and then VS would crash: I checked the logs, but they were not helpful at all. The error, as shown below, is An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.

[image]

This might be where the error was thrown. Not sure

```
    <entry>
    <record>3863</record>
    <time>2016/07/20 14:11:46.766</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: key&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Extensions.ExtensionsManager.OnTextViewCreated(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Controller.TextViewConnectionListener.OnTextViewGotAggregateFocus(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Commands.Html.VsHtmlTextViewConnectionListener.OnTextViewGotAggregateFocus(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Controller.TextViewConnectionListener.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass24_0.&lt;OnTextViewConnected&gt;b__0(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent(Object sender, EventHandler eventHandlers)</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
```

This makes it so I have to manually merge my cshtml files. I tried repair VS 2015 and also tried to disable a bunch of extensions, but it's still there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wanted to post a fix for this, because I had issues finding it. I found this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/293) on GitHub, which suggested that I go to Tools, Options, Text Editor, HTML, Advanced and then set **Identify Helpful Extensions** to **False**. This was suggested in a post by ToddGrun at least, and maybe some others.

[image]

I went ahead and restarted Visual Studio before attempting to merge again. Not sure if you have to do that.

It worked after that.

Comment: Those helpful extension messages had been annoying me anyway by appearing again after I'd clicked "don't ask again" so double win from this fix.

Comment: This fixed my problem (and I even did a full repair). I didn't need to restart VS though to complete the merge.